# How to get into breakpoints in a .exe project

Tags: c++

Actually I am having two Projects of .exe for example A and B. When I start executing the project A with a button click a link has be created and automatically it calls for the B project and a GUI is loaded. For editing purpose I have to debug the Project B, when I am trying to keep a break point in the project B the compiler is not coming into the breakpoints. So how to enter into that breakpoints.
  can anybody pls help me out.

Comment: One way is to put a loop at the beginning of the second program that's dependent on a variable, then once it is running you can attach the debugger, put a breakpoint inside the loop and change the variable so the loop ends and you can continue on debugging.

Comment: Run project A in one IDE/Debugger, and run project B in a second IDE/Debugger.

Comment: I wonder if there is anything (for the particular C++ environment) like `Debug.Assert(false)` in .NET - it prompts to attach a debugger. Very handy to have at the start of programs executed 'live'.

Comment: thanks for u r answers. In my code there is no such debug.assert.

Answer (score 0):

There are typically two options.

**Attach the debugger to the running process**

- Load project B in your IDE.
- Start process A external to the IDE. For instance, double click it's .exe file.
- In process A perform the action that results in process B being started.
- In the IDE, attach to process B and start debugging it.

**Specify a host process**

- Load project B in your IDE.
- Specify in the IDE config for project B that process A is to be the host executable.
- Start debugging from the IDE. This will create process A rather than process B because process A is the host.
- In process A perform the action that results in process B being started.
- The IDE notices that process B has started and starts debugging it.

Precisely how you do this depends on which tools you use and will be described in the documentation.